# Does the continuity at $0$ of the addition map in a vector space imply its continuity?

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, quotient-spaces

I have a question about the proof of Theorem 1.41 in Rudin, *Functional Analysis, 2/e.* The theorem states

> Let $N$ be a closed subspace of a topological vector space (t.v.s.) $X$. Let $\tau$ be the topology of $X$ and define $\tau_N$ as the quotient topology of $X/N$. Then $\tau_N$ is a vector topology on $X/N$; the quotient map $\pi:X\to X\backslash N$ is linear, continuous, and open.

The text first proves that $\tau_N$ is a topology, and that $\pi$ is linear, continuous, and open, which are all fine. Then it attempts to show that the addition map in $X\backslash N$ is continuous:

> *Proof.* ... If now $W$ is a neighborhood of $0$ in $X\backslash N$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $0$ in $X$ s.t. $$V+V\subset \pi^{-1}(W).$$ Hence $\pi(V)+\pi(V)\subset W.$ Since $\pi$ is open, $\pi(V)$ is a neighborhood of $0$ in $X\backslash N$. Addition is therefore continuous in $X\backslash N$.

I understand every step in the proof, but I think this only shows that $\pi$ is continuous at $0$, not that it is continuous in $X$.

I know that by Theorem 1.17 in the book, if $X$, $Y$ are t.v.s.'s and $\Lambda:X\to Y$ is a linear mapping continuous at $0$, then it is continuous. But this requires that $X$ and $Y$ are t.v.s.'s, and if we know that $X\backslash N$ is a t.v.s., there would be nothing to prove here!

Am I missing something here? My question is: **Does continuity at $0$ imply continuity in this problem? If so, how?** Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It is not mentioned how large the neighborhood $V$ is, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar No. Only that $ V+V \subset \pi^{-1}(W) $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, continuity of a group product at 0 implies continuity everywhere for a group equipped with a topology that is translation bi-invariant: Meaning if $U$ is open then $g \cdot U$ and $U \cdot g$ are open for any $g \in G$. In particular, a vector space under addition is an abelian group and so this theorem applies. (Hopefully, by construction it is clear that this topology satisfies the translation-invariant property).

EDIT: Here's an explicit proof of the vector space case, which easily generalizes: Suppose $V$ is a vector space equipped with a topology such that $+$ is continuous at $0$, and whenever $U$ is an open set and $v \in V$, $v + U$ is also open.

Now, we'll show $+:V \times V \rightarrow V$ is continuous at $(v,w)$. Let $U \subset V$ be an open set containing $v + w$. Then, the set $\tilde{U} = -(v + w) + U$ is an open set containing $0$, and so there exist open sets $U_1$ and $U_2$ containing $0$ such that $U_1 + U_2 \subset \tilde{U}$ (by continuity of addition at 0). Then the sets $v + U_1$ and $w + U_2$ are open sets containing $v$ and $w$ respectively, and $(v + U_1) + (w + U_2) \subset (v + w) + \tilde{U} = U$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a weak background in algebra and I don't quite understand your answer. Is there an elementary proof for that the continuity of addition map at zero implies its continuity (that doesn't use algebraic concepts explicitly, but only analysis)? Thank you!

Comment: Hey Fang, I've edited my comment. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the edit! There is just one thing: To show that $\tau_N$ is translation invariant, let $U$ be an open set in $X/N$, and $a\in X$. Then $\pi(a)+U = \pi(a)+\{\pi(x):\pi(x)\in U\}=\{\pi(a+x):\pi(x)\in U\}.$ Hence $\pi^{-1}(\pi(a)+U)=\pi^{-1}\left\{\pi(a+x):\pi(x)\in U\right\}=a+\pi^{-1}(U).$ I think this is how we tackle it, but I'm not sure about the vary last equality. Could you please give me some help?